# Please can someone help identify or translate the artist name?

Tags: translation

Can anyone help identify this painting or the artist?

[images here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Antiques/comments/14u7w8w/can_anyone_help_identify_this_painting_or_the/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=ioscss&utm_content=2&utm_term=1)
I’ve had this beautiful silk painting for a couple of years now and would love to get any insight if possible! It’s about 50cm x 20cm and I’ll attach pictures of full painting with the signature. Any help identifying the artist or the era when it was made would be much appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The artist of picture **seems** (I have discovered contradictions on Baidu Baike regarding 石舟, specifically inconsistencies in the birth year of the same individual.) is a person named [郭子美](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E9%83%AD%E5%AD%90%E7%BE%8E?fromModule=lemma_inlink), Pen name is [石舟](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%9F%B3%E8%88%9F/5120455).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Despite the inconsistency in the ages of 郭子美 and 石舟 on Baidu Baike, it is certain to say that the author is  石舟.

Answer (score 0):

[image] [image]

The characters, next to the seal on the left upper corner, are 石舟 (from top down), potentially the name of the painter.

Here is more info on  https://www.reddit.com/r/ArtHistory/comments/14u7rzg/does_anyone_know_anything_about_this_painting_or/